# Getting Error: "No space left on device" for a particular filename

Tags: linux, hard-drive, filesystems, ext4

I have a ext4 volume with lot of files inside a particular directory.

Whenever I am trying to create a file inside it of a particular name, I am getting "No space left on device" error.

```
$ touch /data/lake/http:____images__br037__319854_366_tp.jpg
touch: cannot touch ‘/data/lake/http:____images__br037__319854_366_tp.jpg’: No space left on device
```

**If I change even one letter of the filename, it works.**

Here is the disk usage and inode usage for that volume:

```
# df -h /dev/xvdf
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvdf       985G  679G  256G  73% /data

# df -i /dev/xvdf
Filesystem       Inodes    IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvdf      65536000 24751661 40784339   38% /data
```

I ran fsck also to make sure that its not a disk corruption issue.

```
# e2fsck -y /dev/xvdf
e2fsck 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
/dev/xvdf: clean, 24751661/65536000 files, 182020406/262144000 blocks
```

Can someone help me how can i debug it further.

Comment: Which "one letter" did you change?

Comment: report bug for ext team

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Actually any letter change is working. I tried changing jpg for jp and it worked.

Comment: Xvd is a Xen virtual disk. It may be represented by one or more large files on the hypervisor host which grow only when necessary. Check whether the host is out of disk space.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick This is an AWS instance. I don't know how to check that. Can you tell me how i can find out. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to administer AWS disks. If the management console doesn't provide any info, you might open a trouble ticket.

Comment: test with `du -sh yourfile`

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh: It says "No such file or directory"

Comment: replcae `____images__br037__319854_366_tp.jpg`

Comment: You need to retrive real size of this.

Comment: I tried creating `____images__br037__319854_366_tp.jpg` file. It works. but not working for `/data/lake/http:____images__br037__319854_366_tp.jpg`

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh I didnt understand what you mean by saying retrieve real size. Can you please explain how to do that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23466/discussion-between-pradeepchhetri-and-mohsen-pahlevanzadeh).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be a known bug in the dir_index feature (which you should be able to disable) that is caused by hashes of filenames colliding:

http://blog.merovius.de/2013/10/20/ext4-mysterious-no-space-left-on.html

Comment: Very interesting! @pradeepchhetri , how many files are in that directory?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick That directory contains 7859825 files.

Comment: Disabling dir_index may fix the problem but it's likely to have a horrible performance impact. I expect the real soloution is either to move to a different filesystem or avoid putting so many files in one dir.